How to quickly find the source of a specific theorem or property?
Mathematics has so many theorems, properties, and formulas to memorize. When solving math problems, you need to apply the theorems, properties, and formulas you have learned. When studying new concepts, proofs, or derivations in a textbook, you also rely on the theorems and properties you have learned.
If you forget these theorems and properties, you might not be able to understand the derivations of formulas. However, sometimes your memory becomes fuzzy, and you can't recall the conditions of a property or the correct application of a formula. You urgently need to find the source of this formula or theorem quickly. But at that moment, you can't remember which book the theorem is from, or which chapter of the textbook it’s in. You might think it’s in Chapter 3, but you can’t find the theorem anywhere in that chapter!
What should you do in such a situation? Sometimes, I spend a lot of time just trying to find the source of a particular property!
For example, you come across a math problem that could be solved quickly by applying a certain property. However, your memory is unclear—you’re not sure if such an equation actually exists. Or perhaps you can’t remember the prerequisites for using this equation, such as the conditions on g(x) or any restrictions on f(x). At this point, you need to locate the source of this property in a math book to verify it. You might suggest looking under topics like "Limits of Composite Functions" or "Composite Functions." Of course, that could work if you’re lucky enough to remember a few keywords. But you can’t always rely on luck. Some formulas, theorems, and properties are listed in textbooks as "Theorem 1" or "Property 3," without memorable keywords. In such cases, the effort required to find their source becomes much greater!
$$\lim_{x\to c}f\big(g(x)\big)=f\big(\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\big)$$

Is this an actual issue? I take it you’re just starting out.

The most important property a mathematician needs to have is patience. After a while you will notice that the instances where you "quickly" need to find a source become less. Also: the best sources will mostly be your own notes.

WikiProof is a good aid, it is well organized and have easy-to-read proofs
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Category:Branches_of_Mathematics
If you have some particular mathematical equation in mind you could perhaps use https://approach0.xyz
Besides that, perhaps keeping some notes of important theorems or properties that you can review? That could also be helpful, but my advice is to not try to memorize theorems, that may limit your imagination.
Explanation of this latter statement:
Proofs have some structure/pattern that is sometimes repeated among the proofs of the same area, if you get too used to those patterns then when you face some theorem that is impossible to proof using those methods you will probably fail to do it because you are too used to those known patterns of proofs that you have memorized.
One thing is study a proof but another is memorize it like a song. To do mathematics, in my opinion, you should have some room for creativity that is incompatible with over-memorization. Of course as you progress in your career many proofs will become easy to remember, but this is different from forcing yourself to memorize them.

Thank you for recommending the tool; it's been very helpful. However, I don't quite understand your statement, "but my advice is to not try to memorize theorems, that may limit your imagination." Why would memorizing more theorems limit one's imagination?

@bokabokaboka explanation in the edit! Best regards
